# Shutdown spawned java child process gracefully

Tags: java, process

I use `ProcessBuilder` to spawn a child process for executing writing some data to  file system. And a problem occurs because the parent process may crash/ killed unexpectedly, the child process just hangs even I use e.g. `jps` checking if its parent process dies then exits. What is the right way for a spawned child process to detects if its parent process is dead and then exit?

Also, After searching on the internet, most solution use `Runtime.addShutdownHook()`, but this is not provided in `ProcessBuilder`. Does it have equivalent one?

Answer (score 3):

You did a good search around the problem. So you may want to use the returned reference to the `Process` instance and the `Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread)` method you mentioned. This is the last step that I believe you need to take:

```
List commands = new ArrayList();
commands.add("xeyes"); // launch this command
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
final Process p = pb.start();
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    p.destroy();
  }
});

Thread.sleep(2000); // sleep for some time
```

Comment: This is for the entire system shutdown though. While it works in most cases, ideal would be if it worked on the inherited process.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I implemented a heartbeat mechanism where the parent process had to regularly send heartbeats. If that did not happen the child process would shut itself down.